# Assign multiple values to dropdown option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm wanting to assign multiple values to one dropdown selection which are then summed in a text field.

So for example, I might have three drop-down items: Appetizer, Entree, Side. I might have two resulting fields: Calories and Cost. This means that if someone selects "Salad" from the appetizer dropdown, "Salad" needs to have both a cost and calorie value associated with it. Said value will also need to sum whatever the calorie and cost values from the entree and side dropdowns are.

Per another answer on the site, I started out with the following code to sum values from multiple dropdowns: http://jsfiddle.net/sf1hwp2y/

HTML:

```
<select name='anch1'>
 <option value='0'>Appetizer</option>
 <option value='20'>Option 1</option>
 <option value='30'>Option 2</option>
 <option value='40'>Option 3</option>
</select>

<select name='anch2'>
 <option value='0'>Entree</option>
 <option value='20'>Option 1</option>
 <option value='30'>Option 2</option>
 <option value='40'>Option 3</option>
</select>

<select name='anch3'>
 <option value='0'>Side</option>
 <option value='20'>Option 1</option>
 <option value='30'>Option 2</option>
 <option value='40'>Option 3</option>
</select>

<div id='sum'>Calorie Total</div>
```

Javascript + JQuery:

```
$('select').change(function(){
    var sum = 0;
    $('select :selected').each(function() {
        sum += Number($(this).val());
    });
     $("#sum").html(sum);
});
```

I am unsure how to also assign prices or other attributes to the dropdown selections. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably use data- attributes on the

Something like this:

```
<select name="anch1">
    <option value="0">Appetizer</option>
    <option value="20" data-cost="5">Option 1</option>
    <option value="30" data-cost="10">Option 2</option>
    <option value="40" data-cost="20">Option 3</option>
    <option value="50" data-cost="50">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

Then, with your JS:

```
$('select').on('change', function(){
    var sum = 0;
    var cost = 0;

    $('select :selected').each(function() {
        sum += Number($(this).val());
        cost += Number($(this).data('cost'));
    });
    $('#sum').html(sum);
    $('#cost').html(cost);
});
```

Comment: `+1` I would go further and have both `data-cost` and `data-calories`, and reserve `value` to hold the actual choice -- a name or idNumber of the menu item chosen. The two data items can be used to show the end-user the totals, while the value is what actually gets saved, or sent to the kitchen, or whatever.

Comment: @StephenP Yeah, I did consider that, but was being a bit lazy if I'm honest! Great idea though. It'd also allow for more expansion in the future - Perhaps adding Ingredients, allergy information etc, too.

Answer (score 1):

You can put multiple values separated by a delimiter, then use `.split()` to split it up.

```
<select name='anch1'>
 <option value='0,0'>Appetizer</option>
 <option value='20,10.0'>Option 1</option>
 <option value='30,5.99'>Option 2</option>
 <option value='40,3.50'>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

```
$('select').change(function(){
    var total_calories = 0;
    var total_price = 0;
    $('select').each(function() {
        let [calories, price] = $(this).val().split(",");
        total_calories += parseInt(calories);
        total_price += parseFloat(price);
    });
    $("#calories").text(total_calories);
    $("#price").text(total_price);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

just add options properties like `data-price='123'` and then retrieve them with `$(this).attr('data-price')`